# Python Pandas reading UTF-8 characters

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to read an Excel file containing the Swedish characters åäö.

I am importing the Excel file with pd.read_excel(path, sheetname, encoding='utf8')

Works fine to import it and I can see the åäö characters, but when I work with the data for example creating a new variable df['East'] = df['Öst'] + 50 I receive an error message 
Ascii codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 33: ordinal not in range

Anyone that can help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your installed version of Pandas.
Pandas 0.23.4 [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) documentation doesn't mention the parameter.

What you could try: Export the Excel file to CSV and read that in through read_csv, which [supports the encoding-param](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Exporting it to a CSV file and load the data from the CSV file worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Double Check if Excel is saved as UTF-8

In Excel 2016 When saving as: click More Options > Tools > Web Options > Encoding > Save this document as ... (pick UTF-8 from the list)

Saving Excel as csv or even txt helps in many cases too.
If csv or txt exported from Excel also doesn't open/work properly
open it in notepad and save it again selecting proper UTF-8 encoding